# how to install solr with nginx on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: nginx, solr, ubuntu-12.04

I downloaded solr-4.7.0.tgz. Extracted it in /opt/solr. I have nginx. So can anyone guide me the steps to configure solr with nginx. OS is ubuntu 12.04. Also how to configure solr.xml and where to keep it in nginx environment.

Answer (score 0):

Solr is self contained, and already includes a web server (Jetty). Once Solr is running, the only use for Nginx with Solr is to use it as a front-end proxy, e.g. for access control purposes.

http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/reverse-proxy/